# React native class re-renders every time when I change state variable

Tags: javascript, react-native, setstate

I am new to react-native and I'm working on a music player app. I have a timer to update the value for a progress bar which indicates how much audio has been played.

When I update the timer value my whole class is re-rendered every seconds so I can not handle play, pause, and seek events.

Comment: Hi @Krrunal can you add some code?

Comment: is your progress bar value in same component which you whole screen is? then if you update the value with setState() your whole screen will be updated. to avoid that you can create another component for progress bar which has its own state

Answer (score 0):

use shouldComponentUpdate to control the re-redering 
for example if you does not want to render component on Timer change

```
shouldComponentUpdate(newProps, nextState) {
    if (nextState.timer !== this.state.timer) return false
    return true;
}
```